Можно ли писать слова через дефис, когда одно из слов в кавычках:
Например, есть кот, и этот кот вроде как друг, то есть "друг". Можно ли писать "друг"-кот?

Нельзя! В кавычки заключаются слова, а при дефисном написании словосочетание приравнивается к слову.

Как тогда писать?)

Что значит вроде как друг, т.е. "друг"? В этом предложении набор слов.

@Буратино Как писать? Нужно привести предложение и контекст, чтобы решить эту задачу.  Те есть зачем вам нужны кавычки –  цитирование, ирония или что?  И главное, что у вас за идея в теме с другом-котом. Пока это непонятно.

У меня есть кот. Я с этим котом не особо лажу, но пусть он будет мне "друг" или "дружок". И вот этот "дружок"-кот ...

И вот этот "дружок-кот"  отличился очередной раз...  Только так, какие сомнения?

но он же настоящий кот, а не "кот".

При дефисном написании это единое понятие "кот как друг", а не просто кот.

Может тогда правильно мой кот "друг", как фирма "Кот и сыновья"? То есть дефис лишний?

Нет,  кавычки имеют разное значение. Фирма "Кот и сыновья" - название, а "дружок-кот"  в ироническом смысле.

В ироническом смысле что?

"Кот как дружок" и, следовательно,  "дружок-кот",
